BTC stuck on Phantom Wallet: Unable to transfer remaining balance or bridge
I currently have BTC stuck on my Phantom Wallet. Initially, I was able to transfer half of the total amount successfully. However, I am now experiencing multiple issues preventing me from accessing or moving the remaining balance.
Details of the situation:
1.  My Phantom Wallet is connected to the Solana network.
2.  I successfully transferred around half of my BTC balance earlier.
3.  Now, when I try to transfer the remaining balance, the wallet sets a maximum transferable limit of $500, even though my balance is higher .
4.  When I attempt to transfer even this limited amount, I get an error message, and the transfer fails.

Additional checks and issues:
•   I verified the network status on Mempool, and there are no pending transactions or congestion issues.
•   I connected my Phantom Wallet to Portal Bridge (a bridging site), hoping to bridge my BTC or Wrapped BTC (WBTC) to another network. However:
•   BTC or WBTC does not appear in my wallet on Portal Bridge, preventing me from using the bridge functionality.
Current observations:
•   My BTC balance appears correct in Phantom, but it seems partially unspendable.
•   I cannot identify whether the issue is with unspent transaction outputs (UTXOs), a technical limitation, or a bug.
Questions:
1.  Why is my Phantom Wallet restricting the transfer of my BTC to a maximum of ~$500, even though my balance is much higher?
2.  Why does BTC or WBTC not appear in my wallet on Portal Bridge, preventing me from bridging?
3.  Could this issue be related to UTXOs or how Phantom Wallet manages BTC?
4.  What steps can I take to unlock or consolidate my BTC to make it spendable or bridgeable again?
Any help or guidance on this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
